# Can a closure be sent to a SendPort

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I'm working on implementation two-isolates app. In this scope I'm exploring a possibility to send a closure via SendPort. The [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html) says that in case isolates share same code anything can be sent with some exceptions. But when I try to call this

```dart
port.send(() {});
```

I get an error:

> E/flutter (26634): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function '':.)

Is that expected behavior and one just can't send functions via SendPort?

My environment is:

```
Flutter 3.3.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b8f7f1f986 (6 months ago) • 2022-11-23 06:43:51 +0900
Engine • revision 8f2221fbef
Tools • Dart 2.18.5 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

Comment: Have you looked into Isolate.run()?  The rules seem a bit more relaxed for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Dart 2.15, which enables [isolate groups](https://dart.dev/language/concurrency#performance-and-isolate-groups) by default, isolates started with [`Isolate.spawn()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-isolate/Isolate/spawn.html) share the same code and allow including closures in inter-isolate messages.

This may fail if the closure's enclosing context contains messages that are not sendable.
Sending closures to isolates is generally discouraged due to this issue. See [dart-lang/sdk#36983](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36983), where this is discussed in relation to another issue.

See the [Dart VM section of the Dart 2.15.0 changelog](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/2.15.0/CHANGELOG.md#dart-vm) for more information.

Comment: I've realized I use a `workmanager` which seems to leverage different native technologies for Android and iOS. Will try pure `Isolate`